# CCAvenue Payment Gateway integration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there a way to integrate CCAvenue in flutter app without using webview. I mean direct in app payment using CCAvenue like we do with razorpay direct implementation in the app we do not have to go to webview something ?

Comment: This might be helpful (unofficial package) https://pub.dev/packages/cc_avenue